# How to change time source from "Local CMOS Clock" to "DC"

Tags: windows, active-directory, ntp, time-synchronization, w32time

In a domain, I want to set DC as time server.

To do that I use this command:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:europe.pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
```

and

```
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

In the client servers I use

```
net time \\<comp.name.of.ad> /set /y
```

but some of the clients still use Local CMS Clock.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I also run

```
w32tm /resync [/computer:<computer>] [/nowait] [/rediscover]
```

on client end but the time server is still Local CMOS Clock for the client.

On the AD source is what I set. (nist.expertssmi.com)

On the clientend, source is Local CMOS Clock

Comment: What is the output of the w32tm /status and is the DC advertising as a time server?  See http://serverfault.com/a/449832/20701

Comment: Have you tried this from the client end -                      w32tm /resync [/computer:<computer>] [/nowait] [/rediscover]

Comment: Did you stop and restart the time service by running this command? 
net stop w32time && net start w32time

Comment: Do you have more rhan one domain controller?  The time server needs to have the PDC FSMO role.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To configure a client computer or a member server to sync time from the domain, run the following command:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update
```

And then stop and restart the time service by running:

```
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

This should be all you need to do.

Comment: This did not work for me. Ran the above commands as admin: `The command completed successfully.`, `The Windows Time service was stopped successfully.`, `The Windows Time service was started successfully.` Still, `Time Server: Local CMOS Clock`.

Comment: Is this on a VM? If so, which hypervisor?

Comment: No, this was on a regular Laptop. Windows 10 is installed, but has not seen the domain server except over limited Cisco VPN in 7 months (Corona). Maybe that's part of the reason. I was able to set `pool.ntp.org` servers using a similar `w32tm` command, but syncing still fails.

Comment: The given problem and solution only are relevant for computers that are joined to a domain.

Comment: The computer in question _is_ joined to a domain. It just hasn't seen the domain controller in a while (but I am still not sure that is why this command has no effect).

Comment: The domhier flag tells the win32time service to use a domain controller as its source. If one isn't available, it probably won't take effect.

Comment: Which is weird, because I set set it to use `pool.ntp.org` without an internet connection. You do not need to be able to communicate with the server to be able to configure using the server. Anyway.

Comment: Fair point, but still, if your computer is rarely connected to a domain where it can sync its time with a domain controller, then it is gradually going to drift out of sync with the domain anyway. In a situation where the computer rarely syncs with the domain, you may be better off skipping domhier and just configuring win32time to use an internet-based time service.

Comment: thank you, been struggling the whole day and it finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

I went thru all the above on my domain joined Windows 10 machine trying to get it to resync. What fixed this for me was I first ran DCDIAG on my domain controller and saw the error that said this server is not advertising as a time server. So then I ran `w32tm /query /status` on my DC. Which returned an answer of vmnic something. My DC was using the time integration services from the Hyper-V host. I went to the Hyper V Manager and went to the setting on my DC and removed the check box from time integration services. Then I reset my DC to use an external time source:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time2.google.com /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update 
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

Now when I went back to my Windows 10 clients I could run:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

That fixed the time sync immediately. After about 15 minutes the rest of my domain joined PC's had also updated to the correct time. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, but the suggestions above didn't help (`w32tm /resync` brought "The computer did not resync because no time data was available"). Until I found out that there was no secure channel to the DC (tested with `nltest /sc_verify:<domain name>`), and the cause was that the machine account password didn't work. I fixed that with `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server "<dc-name>" -Credential <domain admin account>` in a Powershell. Now the `w32tm /query /source` showed that time was received from the DC, and not from CMOS clock anymore.