# Windows clients not syncing time

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, ntp, w32time

I have a basic Windows network and the workstations are not syncing time. I have read and followed the advice in the article below without success:
[How to change time source from "Local CMOS Clock" to "DC"](https://serverfault.com/questions/451204/how-to-change-time-source-from-local-cmos-clock-to-dc)

```
C:\>w32tm /query /source
Local CMOS Clock

C:\>w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update
The command completed successfully.

C:\>net stop w32time && net start w32time
The Windows Time service is stopping.
The Windows Time service was stopped successfully.

The Windows Time service is starting.
The Windows Time service was started successfully.


C:\>w32tm /query /source
Local CMOS Clock

C:\>w32tm /resync /rediscover
Sending resync command to local computer
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything to know about time configuration in Active Directory is available [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nepapfe/2013/03/01/its-simple-time-configuration-in-active-directory/).

Comment: Are the domain controllers advertising as a time server?

Comment: I thought the PDC did this automagically in AD.

Comment: Barry: Thanks for the link. Article states set PDC=NTP and other DCs=NT5DS. Does this also mean workstations should be set to NT5DS too?

Answer (score 1):

I went thru many resync commands on my domain joined Windows 10 machine trying to get it to resync.  What fixed this for me was I first ran DCDIAG on my domain controller and saw the error that said this server is not advertising as a time server.  So then I ran w32tm /query /status on my DC.  Which returned an answer of vmnic something.  My DC was using the time integration services from the Hyper-V host.  I went to the Hyper V Manager and went to the setting on my DC and removed the check box from time integration services.  Then I reset my DC to use an external time source: 
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time2.google.com /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update 
Then run:  net stop w32time and net start w32time 
Now when I went back to my Windows 10 clients I could run: 
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update 
and 
net stop w32time and then net start w32time 
That fixed the time sync immediately.  After about 15 minutes the rest of my domain joined PC's had also updated to the correct time.  Hope this helps you!