# Domain-joined computer won't switch time source to domain from "Local CMOS Clock"

Tags: active-directory, domain, ntp, time-synchronization

My situation is almost identical to the one cited in this post:

[How to change time source from "Local CMOS Clock" to "DC"](https://serverfault.com/questions/451204/how-to-change-time-source-from-local-cmos-clock-to-dc)

I have a domain-joined computer that is showing "Local CMOS Clock" as the source despite my attempts to change it. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Ran the following terminal commands to confirm that the computer clock is off from the network server clock (by about two minutes): `Net time /Domain:local.mydomain.com & Net time \\WORKSTATION-NAME`
2. Ran the following command to confirm that the local machine set to "Local CMOS Clock": `W32tm /query /source`
3. However, running the following commands did not change the setting:
   `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update
   net stop w32time && net start w32time`
4. Running `W32tm /query /source` still returns:
   “Local CMOS Clock”

What do I do now? I'm not sure how to force it to change.

Comment: 1. Don't use the net time command. 2. How long has it been since you reconfigure it with the w32tm commands?

Comment: I did the configuration in the order that I listed above in my question. So after setting the source, I immediately checked it to see if it had been updated. (which it wasn't). What should I use instead of net time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. After you run these commands give it some time to reflect the change. If it hasn't reflected the change after an hour then additional troubleshooting is going to be needed.

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier
w32tm /config /update
net stop w32time
net start w32time
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I ran those commands and waited 1 hour before running W32tm /query /source again but it is still reporting back "Local CMOS Clock". What else can I try to get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

I went thru all the above on my domain joined Windows 10 machine trying to get it to resync. What fixed this for me was I first ran DCDIAG on my domain controller and saw the error that said this server is not advertising as a time server. So then I ran `w32tm /query /status` on my DC. Which returned an answer of vmnic something. My DC was using the time integration services from the Hyper-V host. I went to the Hyper V Manager and went to the setting on my DC and remove the check box from time integration services. Then I reset my DC to use an external time source:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time2.google.com /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

Now when I went back to my Windows 10 clients I could run:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update 
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

That fixed the time sync immediately. After about 15 minutes the rest of my domain joined PC's had also updated to the correct time. Hope this helps you!